# relationship between multiple tables of ms access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a small question regarding the relationships in my project

I have some multiple tables holding some columns and they are related to each other with intermediate tables which are acting in many to many relationship.

**example**: measure(table) `Mea_Id(PK)` in measure table and product(table) `Pro_snr` is primary key in product table and those columns are joined in intermediate table named `Mea_pro` to check which measure is holding which product.

As like this i have several intermediate tables which checks like which product is holding which part numbers and which product is produced in which location with different intermediate tables.

My question is when I am trying to execute the queries by using different intermediate tables those are not working and another thing is i have a primary key `pro_snr` related with different foreign keys as those values are not written in foreign keys.

Here is the relationship diagram hope it will help in solving the problem

The black tables are the intermediate tables

http://tinypic.com/r/95zad1/8 here is the url 
http://i57.tinypic.com/95zad1.png

Comment: i dont have enough reputations to post the image i tried with html but it is not working

Comment: There are many places on the web to share screenshots or printed relationship diagram. Pick one, upload your screenshot and add a link in your question.

Comment: A screen shot won't help.  Your questions are too unclear and broad.

Comment: thank you geoB hope you can help me out after having a look at relationships

Comment: After having a look at the image you get clear image of what iam trying to ask

Comment: Unfortunately, the screenshot is unreadable.

Comment: Can you also post the sql for the queries you are trying to execute?

Comment: SELECT dbo_tbl_Product.PRO_SNR
FROM (dbo_tbl_Measure INNER JOIN dbo_MEA_PRO ON dbo_tbl_Measure.MEA_ID = dbo_MEA_PRO.MEA_ID) INNER JOIN (dbo_tbl_Part INNER JOIN (dbo_tbl_Product INNER JOIN dbo_PRO_PAR ON dbo_tbl_Product.PRO_SNR = dbo_PRO_PAR.PRO_SNR) ON dbo_tbl_Part.PART_SNR = dbo_PRO_PAR.PAR_SNR) ON dbo_MEA_PRO.PRO_SNR = dbo_PRO_PAR.PRO_SNR;